# How to pre-fill a url in HTML

Tags: html, url

I'm trying to send an email ad out to clients when they click on a link to my website, their information such as name, email, and dob is already included on my form.

I'm using this structure right now in the URL and it's pre-filling the name, but nothing else:

```
params=fname/{{firstname}}/lname/{{lastname}}/birthdate/{{dob_year}}/{{dob_month}}/{{dob_day}}/email/{{email}}
```

What do I do?

Comment: How do you retrieve the information from the URL? Can you provide some code?

Comment: Can you show us the code of the form ?

Comment: http://justanexample.com/campaign/index.php?firstname=%%FIRSTNAME%%&lastname=%%LASTNAME%%&emailaddress=%%EMAIL%%

Comment: ignore my last post.... it looks like this:  http://justanexample.com/campaign/index.php?firstname=%%FIRSTNAME%%&lastname=%%LASTNAME%%&emailaddress=%%EMAIL%%                                                                                                      and I was told to fill it like this: http://justanexample.com/campaign/index.php?firstname={{firstname}}&lastname={{lastname}}&emailaddress={{email}}                           but I'm having trouble

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use `/` as separator for birthdate data. Try to use another separator for `year/month/day`

```
params=fname/{{firstname}}/lname/{{lastname}}/birthdate/{{dob_year}}-{{dob_month}}-{{dob_day}}/email/{{email}}
```

If you really need the slash for birthdate then you can handle it before displaying:

PHP example:

```
$date = implode('/', explode('-', $_GET['birthdate']));
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that out.